# Metaphorical "looms" — Une méthaphore similaire aux « métiers à tisser »

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

I'm trying to translate a metaphor of the "mathematical and computational looms" that operate in the background of modern day biology — I think I just translated this without the "looms" idea and just mentioned 'les coulisses'.

Could anyone offer a natural translation of this idea in French? I'd prefer to not just state what I mean literally if possible — makes the prose a little dull!

---

J'essaye de traduire  la méthaphore « mathematical and computational looms » que permet la langue anglaise. L'idée que je cherche à formuler c'est que ces « métiers à tisser », mathématiques et « computationnels » , font partie du bagage de la biologie moderne. J'ai traduit ça sans l'idée de « looms », en mentionnant « les coulisses ».

Y a-t-il une traduction plus naturelle en français ? Si possible, je préfèrerais ne pas traduire cette idée de façon littérale — un peu de finesse serait la bienvenue.

Comment: To remain in the weaving area, « [trame](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trame_(tissage)) » ?

Comment: @Édouard: « la trame mathématique qui sous-tend la biologie moderne » ? Je pense qu'en élaborant un peu tu peux en faire une réponse.

Answer (score 4):

Il me semble que le mot « loom » comporte au moins deux idées : les mathématiques sont un outil ; les mathématiques sont un support. Difficile de transposer ces deux idées dans une même métaphore qui fonctionne en français.

« Les coulisses » me déplait particulièrement car il contient l’idée d’une volonté, sinon de secret, au moins de volonté de discrétion. Or je crois que cette dimension est absente ici.

Si l’on veut rester dans le domaine du textile, je suggère « **canevas** »<sup>1</sup> sur lequel on peut « broder » la biologie moderne. Ce mot transmet bien l’idée que la biologie moderne repose sur les mathématiques et la traitement de données ; on pert toutefois l’idée « d’outil ».

Si l’on veut conserver l’idée d’outil, on peut éventuellement parler de « machinerie mathématique sous-jacente à la biologie moderne », mais le terme me donne l’impression que ladite machinerie fonctionne sans effort ou presque.

---

1. Mon commentaire suggérait « trame », mais je confondais « [fil de trame](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fil_de_trame) » et « fil de chaîne ». Je ne suis pas certain que « chaîne » soit bien compris des lecteurs.

Comment: La *trame* est la 'colonne vertébrale' d'un tissu, comme les mathématiques et le traitement de données le sont pour la biologie. **Les ateliers** conviendraient, aussi bien pour tramer que pour tisser des canevas ... (ateliers dans lesquels *les petites mains* sont actives, mais cette proposition a été refusée et ma réponse retirée).